# How to lower the time to brute force a hash sha256 based on a chain?

Tags: hash, sha256

I have a list of sha256 hashes

```
hash1
hash2
hash3
hash4
```

Each hash value is a hash from the above value(`hash("sha256","hash1") = hash2`). I need to brute force the one thats next in the line(hash0). Is there a way I can lower the time of bruteforcing it knowing that its value hashed equals to the net one in the chain? If so, how can it be done? Or in the worst case scenario, how much time would i take to decrypt it?
Pardon me I am a really bad explainer.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Hashes are not encryption and thus can not be decrypted. The best we can do is try possibilities aka brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might take a while:

On an iPhone 6s SHA256 takes 2.5ms.
Seconds in a year: 23.82K or about 2^25.
Dividing yields 10G or 2^34  hashes per year.
Dividing again 2^256 / 2^34 = 2^222 or in decimal about
100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years.

Look at the bright side, that is much less than a [google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol) years!

This is why it is said that brute forcing SHA256 is not possible.

But you might get lucky and it will take less than a seconds. Do you feel lucky?

Comment: Not at all after your comment, haha